# how to check COndition in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, where-clause

```
SELCT * FROM @Locations Loc
    INNER JOIN SubProposal SP ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
    WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
    AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0
    CASE WHEN (@AS22_RightOfPledgeNum <> '') THEN
    AND (SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as22_RightOfPledgeNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')= @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum) ELSE 1 
    END
```

it throws error near the case condition "Incorrect syntax near CASE

how do I need to check the above condition I need to inlude this statement only when

```
 CASE WHEN (@AS22_RightOfPledgeNum <> '') THEN
    AND (SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as22_RightOfPledgeNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')= @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum) ELSE 1 
    END
```

Comment: Do you _really_ need `CASE` to acheive what you want? The syntax looks wrong too - CASE whould be part of an expression, but in your case it is not.  You'd normally do something like:  `WHERE something = CASE WHEN....`

Comment: if not case what can I use there to check the condition any code snippet.?

Comment: HINT: Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. The first answer, below, isn't quite right. I realized right after I posted that I'd misread the query. You want different WHERE clauses based on a variable. So you need an IF statement outside the query because SQL can't understand CASE the way you're trying to use it.
Not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. Your `WHERE` statement needs to have a condition to test against. If I understood your point,

```
IF @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum <> ''
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM @Locations Loc
        INNER JOIN SubProposal SP 
            ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
        WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
            AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0
            AND (SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as22_RightOfPledgeNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')= @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum) 
ELSE
        SELECT * FROM @Locations Loc
        INNER JOIN SubProposal SP 
            ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
        WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
            AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0;
```

Old answer (not quite on the money):
You're trying to apply a different WHERE clause based on the data in a row. WHERE clauses are applied to the full data set, though. You need to separate your data into two sets, and apply the correct WHERE clauses to each set individually.

Add your CASE criteria to the JOIN conditions, to limit the data pulls to the rows you're interested in, then apply the WHERE conditions you want to each set.

Something like this:

```
SELCT * FROM @Locations Loc
    INNER JOIN SubProposal SP 
        ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
        AND @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum <> ''

        WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
    AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0
    AND (SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as22_RightOfPledgeNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')= @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum) 
UNION ALL
SELCT * FROM @Locations Loc
    INNER JOIN SubProposal SP 
        ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
        AND @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum = ''

    WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
    AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0;
```